# Source implementation available for FxCop rule CA2241 (Provide correct arguments to formatting methods)?

Tags: fxcop

I'm attempting to implement my own version of CA2241 using the `VisitMethodCall` override.

It works if the number of arguments to String.Format are 5 or fewer, but always shows only 2 arguments if there are 6 or more arguments (including the format string).

For example `(MethodCall)call.Operands.Count` is correct in these cases:

```
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "{0} {1}", 1, 2 ) );
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "{0} {1} {2}", 1, 2, 3 ) );
```

...but always returns only '2' in this case:

```
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "{0} {1} {2} {3}", 1, 2, 3, 4 ) );
Console.WriteLine( String.Format( "{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ) );
```

Here is my abbreviated current override for `VisitMethodCall`.  When `expression.NodeType` is not `Literal`, or `Call` it is always `Pop` with only two parameters. And this situation only occurs when the number of arguments to `String.Format` is 6 or more.

```
public override void VisitMethodCall( MethodCall call )
{
    MemberBinding mb = call.Callee as MemberBinding;
    if ( mb.BoundMember.FullName.StartsWith( "System.String.Format(" ) )
    {
        Expression expression = call.Operands[ 0 ];
        switch ( expression.NodeType )
        {
        case NodeType.Literal:
            // ...
            break;
        case NodeType.Call:
            // ...
            break;
        default: // always NodeType.Pop with two parameters
            // ...
        break;
        }
    }
    base.VisitMethodCall( call );
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong?  Also, is source available for the CA2241 rule?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've discovered this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/04/14/data-flow-analysis-rules-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx which explains that CC2241 has been reimplemented using the new Data Flow Analysis engine (Pheonix), and sure enough I was able to find the method with dotPeek.  Unfortunately, there's no documentation for the new DFA engine that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're only seeing two operands once you get past 3 substitute values is that the target is invoking the `Format(string format, params object[] args)` overload of String.Format.  If you want to know how many substitute values are being passed, you will need to examine the size of the `args` parameter array.

There is no source code available for the Microsoft-provided FxCop rules, and there is no rule SDK available.  If you want to learn about how they are built, you'll need to use a decompiler (like pretty much every single other person who writes custom rules).

Comment: Thanks @Nicole.  That confirms what I'm discovering.  The approach I took to check each method works until the IL call to String.Format wraps up the params in an object[] array, but I think using `VisitMethod` won't work in that in the situations, the first argument to `String.Format` doesn't appear to have a type, where I would expect it to be a `Literal`.

I found this post you made a few years ago which may be what I have to do:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstscode/thread/40a57dba-c1b9-4cb7-b41a-d13fad3ab23c